SVG pixelized edges in Android Jetpack Compose
I converted the logo from SVG to XML in Android Studio. One change I had to make was replacing 'Fill' with '#pattern' with 'FillColor' because #pattern is not supported in Android. I don't think that caused my problem, but it might be important to mention.
The logo behaves crazy. On a real 6.5-inch device, the quality is very high. However, on a real 5.7-inch device, I get jagged edges. On a 6.7-inch emulator, the logo appears pixelated as well.
Image(
    imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.logo_white),
    contentDescription = "logo_white",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset(y = 90.dp)
        .sharedElement(
            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = "logo_white"),
            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
            boundsTransform = { _, _ -> tween(durationMillis = 1000) }
        )
)


I suspect you'll need to post both the SVG file and the resultant xml also.

Unfortunately, I can't. So, are you suggesting that the conversion is at fault?

I think it's likely, yes. But without seeing both, it's impossible to be sure.

Okay, that make sense. Any ideas how to convert it to the android xml standards? Built in converter doesn't do that

there's details on the android dev site. (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg-support) about what's supported and what's not. Take this back to the designer and get them to remove those features not supported and try again.

Without seeing the detail of what's in the SVG image and the resultant xml file, it's difficult to say what went wrong.
It sounds to me like there is something in the SVG that is not supported in the vector xml, and so removing those unsupported SVG features from the source file will allow you to convert it to xml again with a better chance of achieving the result your after.
You can find more information about what's supported on the android developer site. (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg-support).
